# SessionStorage different pages Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sessionstorage

I am trying to set my background color on the firstpage, and then trying to get the sessionstorage background for the second page. This is what I got:

First Page:

```
function NatureBackground()
{
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/background-nature.jpg")');
    sessionStorage.setItem('background', 'images/background-nature.jpg')
}
```

Second Page:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('background') === null)
    {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/background-wood.jpg")');
    }
    else
    {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + sessionStorage.getItem('background') + ')');
    }
});
```

On the first page the background remembers the photo, but the secondpage keeps getting the background-wood.jpg. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those two pages on the same browser tab?

Comment: yes, its my own domain. so the only difference is /pagename.html

Comment: And you are certain that the function `NatureBackground` is executed in the first page before second page tries to access the storage?

Comment: yes, Because the firstpage remembers the background, when I swap between the pages.

Comment: It set `background-wood.jpg` because it is really  `null` ! so in result, `background` sessionStorage not set, so check `NatureBackground()`

Comment: While on the second page, can you check the value of the key from F12 developer tools -> Application -> Storage -> Session storage?

Comment: where are you calling the `NatureBackground()` can you post that part?